# Kohana ORM Result - How to display?

Tags: string, kohana

Maybe something really simple, I got really big problem with... ORM result.

I'm loading object with relation using with(). It generates following query:

```
SELECT `article`.`id` AS `article:id`, `article`.`name` AS `article:name`
```

Now's my question... how to display article name in the view? Sorry for dumb question, I really can't beliebe I'm asking it.

**Edit**
Here's my code:

```
$activity = $user->activity->with('article')->where('article.status', '=', 1)->find_all()->as_array();
```

Relations are correct for sure. I can swear I saw something similar today morning on the Kohana Forums however cannot find it.

Cheers!

Comment: What does your code look like that calls the ORM?

Comment: @Aaron Hathaway Edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but does it work if you do this:

```
$activities = $user->activity->with('article')->where('article.status', '=', 1)->find_all();
foreach($activities as $activity) {
  echo $activity->name.'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Do not ask please... :) $activity was loaded as a relation in other model so I should display it with: $role->activity->username to display user name. Thanks for suggestion, going to sleep, too much programming today.